# Tic Tac Toe X's and O's

Tags: python, function, class, tic-tac-toe, turtle-graphics

I need to draw my x's and o's so that when I click on a square it draws it in the middle. I heard you can find the midpoint of the square, but I don't know how to do that either. What can I do to make the X's and O's draw in the middle of the squares when I click on them?

```
import turtle



#I need to fix the positions of the X and O's so that they draw more perfectly into the        squares of the board.



class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.u__init_board = []

    def draw_board():
        '''draws a tic-tac-toe board over the 9 turtle squares'''
        t=turtle.Turtle()
        t.ht() # makes the turtle invisable
        t.up()
        t.goto(-40,-40)
        t.down()
        t.forward(240)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(240)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(240)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(80)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(240)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(80)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(240)
        t.left(90)
        t.goto(-40,-40)
        t.left(180)
        t.forward(160)
        t.up()
        t.goto(40,-40)
        t.down()
        t.forward(240)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(80)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(240)

    def setup_board():
        '''Creates 3 rows of 3 turtles using range(0, 240, 80); turtle.Turtle(); up(); shape('square'); shapesize(4, 4, 4);
        color('white'); goto(x, y). Each turtle is registered to respond to click events using onclick(mark).
        Calls draw_grid() once the 9 turtles are on the board.'''
        for y in range(0,240,80):
            for x in range (0,240,80):
             t=turtle.Turtle()
             t.up()
             t.shape('square')
             t.shapesize(4,4,4,)
             t.color('white')
             t.goto(x,y)
             t.onclick(TicTacToe.mark)
        TicTacToe.draw_board()

    def mark(x, y):

        '''Function is invoked whenever a turtle registered to respond to click event is clicked. Creates a turtle and draws
        either a circle or an x centered on the x, y coordinates of the click.
        Be sure to set circle to False once the circle is drawn and to True once the x is drawn. '''
        ct = turtle.Turtle()
        ct.ht() #hides the turtle (makes the turtle invisable)
        ct.up()
        global circle
        if circle:
            turtle.penup()
            #turtle.speed(0)
            turtle.goto(x,y)
            turtle.down()
            turtle.circle(30)
            turtle.left(45)
            circle = False
        else:
            turtle.up()
            #turtle.speed(0)
            turtle.goto(x,y)
            turtle.down()
            turtle.left(45)
            turtle.forward(40)
            turtle.left(180)
            turtle.forward(80)
            turtle.left(180)
            turtle.forward(40)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(40)
            turtle.left(180)
            turtle.forward(80)
            circle = True



    def main():
        wn = turtle.Screen()
        wn.title('OG Tic Tac Toe')
        wn.bgcolor("red")
        global circle
        circle = False
        TicTacToe.setup_board()
        return 'Done'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TicTacToe.main()
    turtle.TK.mainloop()
```

Comment: Go to the top left corner of a square and go down by (height / 2) and to the right by (width / 2). Bam! (Magic)

Comment: I get that, but how do I get that into my code?

Comment: If the `turtle` object moves in pixels, why not use the Pythagorean theorem to find the length of the diagonal side. Then have a `turtle` move that many pixels

Comment: Where do I and how do i put that into my code?

Comment: your code is totally broken it does nothing in its current state ... please post your real code if you want help

Comment: Bro it works, that is my whole code + my comments. Keep in mind that I'm a newbie on coding and this website.

Comment: You already did it. Your `mark` function draws a square or circle at a location `(x, y)` whenever you call the function

Comment: Yeah, but I want it to draw in the middle not where I click

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the X and Y coordinates that the user clicks you can use this information to derive which square they clicked within.
You can use division on the coordinates to identify which square was clicked and then multiplication to place the turtle at the center of that square.
To get started, think about how large each of your squares are.